# How to interpret the output of object detection model in tensorflow.js

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am trying to run custom object detection tensorflow.js model in a browser. I could able to convert tensorflow model to tensorflow.js model (in google colab) using the following command:

```bash
!tensorflowjs_converter \
--input_format=tf_frozen_model \
--output_node_names='detection_boxes,detection_scores,detection_classes,num_detections' \
/content/frozen_inference_graph.pb \
/content/web_model
```

I am sharing the code snippet of `inference.html` file:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"> </script>
<script src="webcam.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <video autoplay playsinline muted id="wc" width="224" height="224"></video>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="startPredicting" onclick="startPredicting()" >Start Predicting</button>
    <button type="button" id="stopPredicting" onclick="stopPredicting()" >Stop Predicting</button>
    <div id="prediction"></div>
</body>

<script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

The code snippet of `index.js` file is as follow:

```js
let model;
const webcam = new Webcam(document.getElementById('wc'));
let isPredicting = false;


async function init(){
        try {
            await webcam.setup();
            model = await tf.loadGraphModel('http://127.0.0.1:8887/model/model.json');
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
}

async function predict() {
    const img = webcam.capture();
    console.log("executing model");
    const cat = document.getElementById('image');
    output = await model.executeAsync(img);
    output.forEach(t => t.print) // log out the data of all tensors
    const data = []
    for (let i = 0; i < output.length; i++){
        data.push(output.dataSync())
    }
    console.log(data);
}

init()


function startPredicting(){
    isPredicting = true;
    predict();
}

function stopPredicting(){
    isPredicting = false;
    predict();
}
```

When I run above `inference.html` file using web server, it returns the following output:

```bash
(4) [t, t, t, t]
0: t {kept: false, isDisposedInternal: false, shape: Array(3), dtype: "float32", size: 400, …}
1: t {kept: false, isDisposedInternal: false, shape: Array(2), dtype: "float32", size: 100, …}
2: t {kept: false, isDisposedInternal: false, shape: Array(2), dtype: "float32", size: 100, …}
3: t {kept: false, isDisposedInternal: false, shape: Array(1), dtype: "float32", size: 1, …}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

The problem is output seems to be irrelevant or I can't understand it. Am I missing something? Please provide me your suggestions. I am sorry for the long post but I am beginner in **tensorflow.js**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`output` is a tf.Tensor. When you called `console.log(output)`, it tries to stringify the object and prints out its `properties`.

The tensor also has the method, `print` to log out its data.

To get the data out of the tensor as a javaScript array, method such as `data` (respectively `dataSync`) and `dataArray` (respectively `dataArraySync`) can be called to retrieve the data aynchronously (respectively synchronously). The data is retrieved as a `typedArray`.

```js
output = await model.executeAsync(img);
// output is an array of tf.tensor.
output.forEach(t => t.print()) // log out the data of all tensors
const data = []
for (let i = 0; i < output.length; i++)
  data.push(output[i].dataSync())  // get the data
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but using the above suggestion it prints error message: `output.print is not a function at predict` and `index.js:21 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: output.data is not a function at predict (index.js:21)`

Comment: Can you please update your question with the definiton of `executeAsync` ?

Comment: Sorry I am not getting your question. I tried to use `model.execute` but I got the following error: `Error: This execution contains the node 'Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/Exit_6', which has the dynamic op 'Exit'. Please use model.executeAsync() instead. Alternatively, to avoid the dynamic ops, specify the inputs [Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/TensorArrayStack_4/TensorArrayGatherV3]`.

Comment: my bad, I thought that `executeAsync` was a function you defined yourself. I edited my question

Comment: I updated the code (also in the question) as suggested by you but still got the following error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: output.dataSync is not a function
    at predict (index.js:23)`

Comment: Sorry, it is `output[i`] instead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205293/discussion-between-saurabh-chauhan-and-edkeveked).

Comment: Could you please help me if possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59719522/running-object-detection-using-tensorflow-js